# Can I use auto completion in quotes?

Tags: bash

I often have to do stuff with directories. For having a shorthand, I put their path into a bash variable, like this:

```
currentProjectPath="Save the blank"
```

I would then like to create some directories inside (or basically do anything with it), but because it contains spaces, I have to quote it:

```
mkdir "$currentProjectPath"
mkdir -p "$currentProjectPath/Ideas/My Ideas/The good ones"
```

It would be great to use auto completion there, but when typing `mkdir "$curr` and then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, nothing happens.

As a workaround, I sometimes type `mkdir $curr`<kbd>Tab</kbd>, which completes it to `mkdir $currentProjectPath`  (inkl. Blank at the end) and then move back to the beginning to add the `"`, but every second time I forget about that.

Is there any possibility to enable auto-completing `$` variable names in quoted strings in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `M-$` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd>) is bound to `complete-variable` and it works inside double-quotes.

Note while what <kbd>Tab</kbd> does in general depends on its context (e.g. you see different possible completions after `cd` and after `set`), `complete-variable` explicitly treats the text before point as a shell variable, nothing else. There are other similarly specialized completion functions (e.g. `complete-hostname`, `complete-username`), you may find them useful. See `man 1 bash` or the [online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Completion.html) to discover them and their default bindings.